# Firebase Web Read from Real-Time Database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display the user's price that they entered in the database, but I'm getting "undefined' back instead of the value that was entered. I didn't get any errors in the console either. How can I fix this? I am using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. I have provided a screenshot and my code.

Studio Dashboard JavaScript code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth();

//const auth = getAuth();
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        readData();
        // ...
    } else {
        window.location.href = "login.html?error";
        alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
    }
});

function readData() {

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid).get().then(snapshot => {

        // Tab One Display
        document.getElementById("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
        document.getElementById("profile-name").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
        document.getElementById("firstName").innerText = snapshot.val().firstName;
        document.getElementById("lastName").innerText = snapshot.val().lastName;
        document.getElementById("lastName").innerText = snapshot.val().lastName;
        document.getElementById("email").innerText = snapshot.val().email;
        document.getElementById("phoneNumber").innerText = snapshot.val().phoneNumber;

        // Tab Two Display
        document.getElementById("servicePrice").innerText = snapshot.val().numberInput;
    }).catch(e => { console.log(e) })
}

function updatePrice() {
    // Get data
    numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    // Enter database location
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid + "/prices/roomA/serviceOne")
        .update({
            //studioName : studioName,
            numberInput: numberInput,
        });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `on` method instead of `get`

```
function readData() {

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {

        //Tab One Display
        document.getElementById("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
        document.getElementById("profile-name").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
        document.getElementById("firstName").innerText = snapshot.val().firstName;
        document.getElementById("lastName").innerText = snapshot.val().lastName;
        document.getElementById("lastName").innerText = snapshot.val().lastName;
        document.getElementById("email").innerText = snapshot.val().email;
        document.getElementById("phoneNumber").innerText = snapshot.val().phoneNumber;

        //Tab Two Display
        document.getElementById("servicePrice").innerText = snapshot.val().numberInput;
    }, (e) => { console.log(e) })
}
```